# How can i use SQL TRIGGER for every 31 December?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Hi  i want to create a trigger that every year in 31 december all old tuples of one table will copied on a specific old_table so there will be dropped.
How can i use trigger for "Every Year" condition?

**Streamline bookings by moving old ones over a year old to a separate entity (HISTORICAL_RESERVATIONS). Do this every year.**

Comment: Use an Event: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html

Comment: There is no such thing as a trigger that runs on calendar time.  You want a scheduled job or event.

Comment: i added the request that i need to request in the question so to be clearer, could you help me write the sql query?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If there's already a script that handles that situation, you could potentially setup a CRON with [this pattern](https://crontab.guru/#59_23_31_12_*) to run it at the end of the year.